# Can someone please answer the given scenarios? I've been trying to understand but got completely stuck

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, software-design

Consider each of the scenarios below and identify the design pattern which is most directly addresses the problem described. Briefly explain your reasoning.

You’ve developed a new implementation of the List interface and you’d like to test the behavior of your new data structure. You’ve written an algorithm to perform your speed tests, but the algorithm needs to make a great many instances of your list class. You want to test the performance of your list against the performance of ArrayList and LinkedList, but you don’t want to have to write your algorithm three times in order for it to be able to create the right kind of list to test.

You’ve completed a compiler for a new language! There are many parts to your compilation process: parsing, transformation, assembly code generation, and so forth. You’d like to allow other programmers to use an interface to compile their code without resorting to system calls or other command-line invocations – your compiler can just run in their processes – but you don’t want those users to have to know how to bring all of the steps of compilation together in order to use your compiler.

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

If you briefly check the existing design patterns (they are not that many), you can figure out which one maps to your given scenario.

*The first scenario* says that the algorithm creates `internally` many instances of the same class, in order to test the performance, so you want to avoid writing the algorithm many times, only to change the class name of the list you want to create.

Only from this short analysis, you can tell that we're talking about a [creational design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern), because we deal with object creation.

If you work through elimination, you can see that [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern is the one which is suited to this scenario, because you want to create multiple objects of concrete classes, which implement the same interface (`List`).

*The second scenario* seems to map more on a [structural design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_pattern) because it relies on the way you design the interface (the API) of your complier logic.

If you check the [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) design pattern (in this structural class), you can see that it really maps on the use-case:

> The facade pattern (also spelled façade) is a software-design pattern commonly used in object-oriented programming. Analogous to a facade in architecture, a facade is an object that serves as a front-facing interface masking more complex underlying or structural code.

Comment: Thank you so much cosmin. Much appreciated

Comment: No worries! Please mark this answer as accepted if you think it’s useful